# jquery submit form with button on event change

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

when a checkbox is checked, i want the form to submit. However I need parameters contained in my submit button to be part of the request.

This bit of script submits the form but not using the button. I guess because jquery submits it some other way.

```
$(e.target).find("input[type='radio']").attr("checked", true)
$(".edit_booking").submit()
```

I've tried pointing jquery to the button containing the params via it's ID and using a click event, but this doesn't work either.

```
$(e.target).find("input[type='radio']").attr("checked", true)
$("#bookings_next").click()
```

Bits of the form:

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form edit_booking" id="edit_booking_9486" action="/venues/plymouth/bookings/9486" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
 .............
<input type="submit" name="forward_button" value="Next step" id="bookings_next" />
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

aha, simple!

```
$('#bookings_next').trigger('click');
```

I have to trigger the event.